# How to insert a line break before an element using CSS

Tags: css

I feel like I saw a way, using the CSS content property, to insert a line break tag before an element. Obviously this doesn't work:

```
#restart:before { content: '<br/>'; }
```

But how do you do this?

Comment: CSS is not for adding or editing content, it is for controlling how content displays.

Comment: It seems to me that layout and flow (line breaks could be considered either) are definitely within the domain of CSS.

Comment: CSS is *absolutely* for adding or editing content when it is a consistent styling element that is a part of your theme. Especially with content management systems like Wordpress that do not allow you to edit your content, its highly useful. That's why the "content" property exists. For adding and/or editing content.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

It's possible using the `\A` [escape sequence](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#cssescapes) in the psuedo-element generated content. [Read more](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#x18) in the CSS2 spec.

```
#restart:before { content: '\A'; }
```

You may also need to add `white-space:pre;` to `#restart`.

note: `\A` denotes the end of a line.

p.s. Another treatment to be

```
:before { content: ' '; display: block; }
```

Comment: Also try white-space: pre-wrap; if you want your text to wrap.

Comment: Brilliant. It should be noted, though, that for this to work - `#restart` must also be `display: inline;`

Comment: This didn't work for me, I used `:before { content: ' '; display: block; }` instead.

Comment: For some reason none of the solutions work with `inline-block` elements. They simply won't go onto the next line. Only solution was to actually append an empty `<div></div>` in the HTML.

Comment: If the line didn't break, you can to use the 'white-space' property
:before { content: '\A'; white-space: pre; }

Comment: :before { content: ' '; display: block; } worked great in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

If `#restart` is an inline element (eg `<span>`, `<em>` etc) then you can turn it into a block element using:

```
#restart { display: block; }
```

This will have the effect of ensuring a line break both before and after the element.

There is not a way to have CSS insert something that acts like a line break *only* before an element and not after. You could perhaps cause a line-break before as a side-effect of other changes, for example `float: left`, or `clear: left` after a floated element, or even something crazy like `#restart:before { content: 'a load of non-breaking spaces'; }` but this probably isn't a good idea in the general case.

Comment: It can't be display:block - because then I would need to display a width for the element to keep its background from running all the way across the page. It needs to be able to auto set the width for the element.

Comment: A `float: left` element might be of some use, as they shrink-to-fit and start on a new line. Otherwise, what you want may not be possible.

Comment: downvoted cause sometimes developers work in a big project where they don't have control or cannot take a decision to apply another solution.

Answer (score 22):

This works for me:

```
#restart:before {
    content: ' ';
    clear: right;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the various unicode characters for new line were not working for me .. ?  This solution did the trick though - thanks!

Comment: Yes, but what happens when you have to put text inside the content too!? [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11750985/2817442)

Answer (score 18):

Following CSS worked for me:

```
/* newline before element */
#myelementId:before{
    content:"\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Excellent idea with plain css

Comment: Worked as a charm for me. I'm using this: `content: 'bar: \a' attr(data-description);`

Answer (score 11):

There are two reasons why you cannot add generated content via CSS in the way you want:

1. generated content accepts content and not markup.  Markup will not be evaluated but displayed only.
2. `:before` and `:after` generated content is added within the element, so even adding a space or letter and defining it as `block` will not work.

There is an `::outside` pseudo element that might do what you want.  However, there appears to be no browser support.  (Read more here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#wrapping)

Best bet is use a bit of jQuery here:

```
$('<br />').insertBefore('#restart');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/sJGH9/1/

Comment: "Using CSS". I found an answer similar to Jesse Kinsman's worked.

Answer (score 11):

Just put a unicode newline character within the before pseudo element:

```css
    #restart::before { content: '\00000A'; }
```

```html
<p>
  The quick brown fox
  <span id="restart">jumps over the lazy dog</span>
</p>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work

Answer (score 6):

Yes, totally doable but it is definitely a total hack (people may give you dirty looks for writing such code).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>lorem ipdum dolor sit <span id="restart">amit e pluribus unum</span></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#restart:before { content: 'hiddentext'; font-size:0; display:block; line-height:0; }
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AprNY/

Comment: +1 For creativity. I've got something that I'm including from an external source and can't alter the actual HTML... this appears to work just fine :) Thanks!

Comment: Due to font-size: 0 this is even hidden from screen readers, and does not seem to split up contents in several parts that are read separately.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
#restart::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: A tip: Add at least a one-liner comment, so your posts don't end up in the VLQQ by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can populate your document with `<br>` tags and turn them on\off with css just like any others:

```
<style>
.hideBreaks {
 display:none;
}
</style>
<html>
just a text line<br class='hideBreaks'> for demonstration
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a new line before text using CSS, you can use the ::before pseudo-element along with the content property and set it to "\A" which represents a line break. Here's an example:

```
.myElement::before {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

In the above code, .myElement represents the selector for the element to which you want to add a new line before the text. The ::before pseudo-element inserts content before the element's content. The content property is set to "\A", which represents a line break. The white-space: pre; property is used to preserve the white space, including the line break.

You can adjust the selector (.myElement) as per your specific element's class or ID, and you can apply this CSS to any element where you want to add a new line before the text.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want the line height to be 20 px

```
  .restart:before { 
     content: 'First Line';
     padding-bottom:20px;
  }
  .restart:after { 
    content: 'Second-line';
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had no luck at all with inserting a break with :before. My solution was to add a span with a class and put the break inside the span. Then change the class to display: none; or display: block as needed.

HTML

```
    <div>
         <span class="ItmQty"><br /></span>
         <span class="otherclass">
              <asp:Label ID="QuantityLabel" runat="server" Text="Qty: ">      
              </asp:Label>
         </span>
         <div class="cartqty">
              <asp:TextBox ID="QuantityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity","{0:#}") %>' Width="50"></asp:TextBox>

         </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 854px)
{
    .ProjItmQty
    {
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1003px)
{
    .ProjItmQty
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the pre-encoded HTML entity for a line break `&#10;` in your content and it'll have the same effect.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me when `content: attr()` is used and the attribute text contains the line break (noting that `white-space: pre-wrap` or similar is also still necessary).

Answer (score 0):

```
body * { line-height: 127%; }
p:after { content: "\A "; display: block; white-space: pre; }
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#x18
The Content Proerty, "newlines"... p will not add margin nor padding at end of p inside parent block (e.g., body › section › p). "\A " line break forces line space, equivalent styled line-height.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of manually adding a line break somehow, you can do implement `border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000` which will take the element's border and only render `border-<side>` of whichever side you specify.

Comment: OP asked for equivallent of `<br>`, not `<hr>`.

Answer (score -2):

Add a `margin-top:20px;` to `#restart`. Or whatever size gap you feel is appropriate. If it's an inline-element you'll have to add `display:block` or `display:inline-block` although I don't think `inline-block` works on older versions of IE.

Comment: No the problem is that the element's display type is inline-block, so I need to have a break before the element.

Comment: the display type is already inline-block. I'm trying to do what I asked above, using the content property.

Comment: You can't add html elements using the content property, it's not possible.

Comment: because your answer would not have solved his problem.  Look at the winning answer which details a way to provide a line break using the content property (which will not accept html elements).  Perhaps it was a misunderstanding of the original question.