# CSS Content to add HTML tags

Tags: html, css

I want to use CSS instead of JavaScript to insert a HTML tag. But the tag gets interpreted as normal text rather than html code.

```
#br:after {
    content: "\003c br\003e"
}


<span>My </span>
<span> Name </span>
<span id="br"> is </span>
<span> XYZ</span>
```

What is getting displayed is:

[image]

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658337/css-content-to-add-html-tags

Comment: @chf you linked to this page. (did you mean [this link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363766/how-to-insert-a-line-break-before-an-element-using-css))

css can't insert html tags, it's for decoration only. You can use effects to simulate a br though, check out the question (same idea with `:after` as `:before`

Comment: Ops http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar effect can be achieved:

```
#br:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2j4JD/

Answer (score 1):

HTML code cannot be inserted, the tags show up as '`<tag>`'.

Comment: You mean as normal text?

Comment: Yeah.............................

Comment: Yeah like normal text http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html