# how to give line break to an anchor without using <br /> or "display:block"

Tags: css, wordpress, line-breaks

I'm using wordpress for making a site. I want "Read more" button to be in second line without using br  or `"display:block"`.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/button-with-line-breaks/

Answer (score 1):

You can add a pseudo `before` element with a `white-space: pre` property. That would do the trick.

```css
a:before {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
teste <a href="#">anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be creating a block-level pseudo-element before the content of the `<a>` element.

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/moxude/1/edit)**

```css
a.readmore:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

Another option would be adding a [line break before the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363766/how-to-insert-a-line-break-before-an-element-using-css) as follows:

[Updated Example](http://jsbin.com/moxude/2/edit)

```css
a.readmore:before {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* or pre */
}
```