# Content property in CSS - how to put content into several paragraphs

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have a block of text that is repeated on several subpages of my web. As I rewrite it from time to time and dont use db, I decided to define it in my css file by pseudoelements (before, after).

Problem is - this text should be in 2 paragraphs and I dont know how to include linebreak in the Content property in css. Found some answers, but no matter what I use (\a, \A, \n) nothing works. Cant use "white-space:pre" as I dont know where those linebreaks will be - all I want to do is to add one more linebreak into Contect.

For better understanding, this is what I want to achieve

[image]

And this is how mI wanted to do it
In css:

> .gettomestia:before 
>   { 
>      content:"How to get to Mestia: ";
>      font-weight:bold; 
>   }
>
> .gettomestia:after 
>   { 
>      content:"longer text in 2 paragraphs";
>      display:inline-block; }

And in aspx file just add span with class = "gettomestia"

I know, its sloppy, but I know no better way. Does anybody know how to enter that linebreak into Content of "after" pseudoelement? Thank you.

Comment: That's not what the `content` property is for. It should be used for **styling** not actual text content. I suggest you rethink your methodology.

Comment: Did you try putting `white-space: pre` into the `:before` pseudo-element itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a line break before an element using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363766/how-to-insert-a-line-break-before-an-element-using-css)

Comment: Add title and use it with attr -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jAYRZw  Hope this works for you

Comment: https://jekyllrb.com/

Comment: torazaburo: Yes, but in this case I need to define all linebreaks, not just that sigle one that divides paragraphs.
Paulie_D: what do you then recommend for repeated blocks of text? Using pseudoelements seemed practical to me.

Comment: If you post a minimal code layout so we can see how you think, we might be able to suggest something better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```css
p:before { 
 content: attr(data-paragraph1) '\00000A' attr(data-paragraph2);
  display: block;
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<p data-paragraph1="This is paragraph 1" data-paragraph2="This is paragraph 2">This is simple paragraph</p>
```