# CSS How do I introduce a 'new line' that for all (variable content) that follows a span with a certain class?

Tags: html, css

In this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zdkL1m9j/ I have text with enumerated spans like `<span class="line_num">[29] </span>`, `<span class="line_num">[30] </span>`, etc. Each span is followed by text and other span elements.

I'm trying to output a view where the content that begins with each `span class="line_num"` (the number `[x]` and subsequent text and elements) begin on a new line (but no 'new line' on the first row - adding `br`will not solve this correctly).

This is all dynamically generated, and due to limitations in the processing, I cannot change the HTML output (or I would use `li` to solve this).

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/zdkL1m9j/3/

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking. Would adding a "display: block;" to your "line_num" class do the trick?

Comment: @Turnip that's just perfect! If you post this as an answer I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: The question has been asked before. I was just clarifying before closing.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't find a suitable answer in SO history but I wasn't using the right vocabulary it seems. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at my [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdkL1m9j/12/):

```
.document-diplo .line_num:not(:first-child):before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
}
```

You can find more details on the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11750985/3623608).

Comment: If you are aware that a question is a duplicate, please do not answer it. And FYI, your selector is far more complex than it needs to be.