# CSS adding line break with content in edge

Tags: css

I'm using this code to add a line break in my css, but doesn't work with the edge, what it could be ?

```
fieldset > legend:before {
    content:"\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a line break before an element using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363766/how-to-insert-a-line-break-before-an-element-using-css)

Comment: thanks, i solve using this code: fieldset > legend {
 white-space: pre; 
}