# Can I use a line break in Paged.js margin box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagination, pagedjs

I am generating a document using [Paged.js](https://pagedjs.org/). As per company policy, the document must have a footer on each page as follows:

| QFxxx ' | *VERIFY REVISION BEFORE USE* Page x / x | MM/dd/yyyy ' |
| --- | --- | --- |

I am having difficulty putting the "verify revision..." and page numbers in the same margin box. My first attempt at this was to use [running-elements](https://pagedjs.org/documentation/7-generated-content-in-margin-boxes/#running-elements%3A-headers%2Ffooter-with-specific-(complex)-content), since the "verify..." needs to bold and italic:

```
<style>
    @page {
        @bottom-center {
            content: element(footRunning);
        }
    }

    .foot-center {
        position: running(footRunning);
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>

<!-- ... -->

<span class="foot-center">VERIFY REVISION BEFORE USE</span>
```

This works insofar as positioning and styling is concerned, but I cannot figure out how to add the page numbers. I wanted to see if using `content` alone could at least achieve the line break ([inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363766/how-to-insert-a-line-break-before-an-element-using-css)):

```
@bottom-center {
    content: "VERIFY REVISION BEFORE USE\APage " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);   
}
```

Instead of line-breaking, however, this only replaced `\A` with a space.

Is there a way for me add line-breaks in the `content` property **OR** to list the page numbers in a running-element?

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone out there with the same issue, I found that it worked well to use a container and adding a child with the `after` pseudo element for the generated content (e.i. page numbers):

```
<style>
    @page {
        margin-bottom: 1in;

        @bottom-center {
            content: element(footRunning);
        }
    }

    .footnote {
        position: running(footRunning);
    }

    .footnote>*:first-child {
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .footnote>*:last-child::after {
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
    }
</style>

<!-- ... -->

<div class="footnote">
    <span>VERIFY REVISION BEFORE USE</span>
    <br>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Make sure to test your margins or the page numbers will go off the bottom of the page.